# how to add C# script that creates and Instantiates a Game Object in Unity game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I know that scripts are added as components to game objects but I have created a game object using C# script. This is the only game object in my simple test game. How should I "add" it to my game? Please see code below:

```
public class TestingHeroPositions : MonoBehaviour {

GameObject hero;
Sprite heroSprite; 

void Start () {

    heroSprite = Resources.Load <Sprite> ("Sprites/heroImage");
    SpriteRenderer renderer = hero.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    renderer.sprite = heroSprite;

    Camera camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
    Vector3 heroPosition = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width/2, Screen.height/2, camera.nearClipPlane));

    Instantiate (hero, heroPosition, Quaternion.identity);

    }

}
```

Comment: Create an empty gameobject and put the script on it.

Comment: I am getting a `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error pointing to the line `SpriteRenderer renderer = hero.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();`

Comment: @Jickery Your hero gameobject is null... Either make it public and set it in inspector or use `GameObject.Find`

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson is solved it by adding `hero = new GameObject();`. Though it's working but there's another error which says `MissingComponentException: There is no 'Camera' attached to the "GameObject" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Camera to the game object "GameObject". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
TestingHeroPositions.Start ()` pointing to the line `Vector3 heroPosition = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width/2, Screen.height/2, camera.nearClipPlane));`

Comment: @Jickery The error is self explanatory. You're trying to access the camera component on this gameobject when their isn't one.. This line `GetComponent<Camera>()`

Comment: Use `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint...` and make sure you have a camera in your scene that is taggeg as `MainCamera`. That is most likely the camera you want to use.

Comment: Why not just use a prefab? Do you really want this fine-grained control?

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 Major Problems. It is the flow of your code.

1 . You're adding a component to an `Object` Class not a `GameObject` Class.
    The `AddComponent` is a member class of GameObject.

2. Like the top problem, Since your `hero` is a GameObject. You are able to set `AddComponent` member of it. But the truth is, it is not Getting Instantiated yet.
3. Instiate is member of `Object` Class not GameObject class, thus it returns an Object class.

To solve.

```
public class TestingHeroPositions : MonoBehaviour {

GameObject hero;
Sprite heroSprite; 

void Start () {





    Instantiate (hero, heroPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
     //Instantiate first then type cast it to GameObject. Instiate returns Object not gameObject.
     //No need for `new GameObject()` Constructor.

    Camera camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
    Vector3 heroPosition = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width/2, Screen.height/2, camera.nearClipPlane));
heroSprite = Resources.Load <Sprite> ("Sprites/heroImage");
        SpriteRenderer renderer = hero.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        renderer.sprite = heroSprite;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, you have used `heroPosition` without declaring it, so it's giving a `NullReferenceException` error

Answer (score 1):

Before instantiating the object add `heroInstance.AddComponent<MonoBehaviour>(this);`. This should work :)

Comment: No it wont. Because the object is not Instantiated and it is not casted to GameObject.

Comment: Sorry, than add ´heroInstance.AddComponent<MonoBehaviour>(this);´

Answer (score 0):

Simple: You create a new game object in your scene, call it (for example) "Hero Spawner" and attach your "TestingHeroPositions" to the "Hero Spawner".

If you want to create multiple heroes, that is the way to go, although your script should be slightly different:

```
public class TestingHeroPositions : MonoBehaviour {

    GameObject heroPrefab;
    Sprite heroSprite; 

    void Start () {
        Camera camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
        Vector3 heroPosition = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width/2, Screen.height/2, camera.nearClipPlane));

        // Instantiate a new instance of heroPrefab into the scene
        var heroInstance = Instantiate (heroPrefab, heroPosition, Quaternion.identity);

        // Only add the hero sprite renderer to THIS instance of the hero Prefab
        heroSprite = Resources.Load <Sprite> ("Sprites/heroImage");
        SpriteRenderer renderer = heroInstance.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        renderer.sprite = heroSprite;
    }
}
```

If you only want to create one hero, you might want to consider letting the Hero object itself (via a component) decide which sprite it has. And if that sprite never changes, maybe just add it to your hero prefab.